# Sequence with basic rule python

Tags: python

I have a question about python. Actuallay I made some code but it did`nt work.

Q: For any positive starting number, by applying the below rule iteratively, you can create a sequence of numbers S that ends with 1.

If Sx is even next number is Sx/2

else next number 3Sx/2

As an example for 13:
S = 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

Find the starting value less than 100,000 that yields the longest sequence S.

```
for x in range (1,100001):
    i=x
    lenght=1
    while i!=1:
        if i%2==0:
            next=i/2
        else:
            next=3*i+1
        lenght+=1
        i=next
```

my code is above. I couldnt find value which has the longest sequencee

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show the code you've tried so far and point out what went wrong.

Comment: Hello, I added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max_val = 1
max_len = 1 # define outside the loop what is the longest sequence 
for x in range (1,100001):
    i=x
    lenght=1
    while i!=1:
        if i%2==0:
            next=i/2
        else:
            next=3*i+1
        lenght+=1
        i=next
    if lenght>max_len: # after every iteration check if the length you found is longer then max_len
        max_len = lenght
        max_val = x
```

max_len = 351

Comment: wow so logical thank yoı so much and How I can find the first value which have 351 lenght